# Windows 7 apps inserted in middle of task bar, instead of added to the end

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, taskbar

When I open instances of the same application in Windows 7 the newly opened instance is inserted in the task bar immediately after the existing instance instead of at the end of the list like Windows XP. Can this be changed?

Edit: Please understand this question is not about combining. I have had combining disabled for a long time. This question is about where in the taskbar new apps are placed, adjacent to other apps of the same type vs at the end of the list (like XP).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**New updated answer** that does exactly what you are looking for (I have tested it).

Download [Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker).

Open it (it is small program that must remain running).

Select the `Don't Group` option:
[image]
Result:
[image]

**Original Answer**

Right click the Taskbar > Properties > Taskbar buttons dropdown > Never Combine (or combine when full) > OK (click small icons checkbox and the taskbar will shrink)

or if you really want it to be like XP

Choose the Windows classic theme. Start > Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Theme > Windows Classic.

*However, I suggest you try the new Windows 7 way, after a week or two it becomes second nature and much more useful than the classic way, IMO anyway.*

Comment: nope :-) it did not become second nature. Neither does opening a new tab in IE. There are needs for organisation and knowing which instance of a program something is. This came before that, and that after this, even the AltTab shows it that way. The taskbar though is always grouping them next to eachother, even in classic , even when not combined?     Add to that, the taskbar can now be re-arranged, but I still cannot Split the conjoined twins.

Comment: Here are some interesting taskbar [tweaks](http://lifehacker.com/5532578/the-power-users-guide-to-the-windows-7-taskbar) including how to get the quick launch back. I don't see one that puts them in order of opening.

Comment: Here is program for just tweaking the taskbar: [tweaks](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) that I've been told does what you ask. Note: I have not used it, but it looks promising.

Comment: I do not use taskbar grouping and I already use the classic theme. My question is about sequential placement of apps in the list of task bar apps.

Comment: @cosmint The program just above your comment works wonderfully. I decided to download it and test it and change my answer to reflect it.

Comment: @opsin Updated answer is right. Very cool.

Comment: Also, this utility defines grouping and combining nicely for us. When I said grouping before I meant combining.

Comment: Wow, I still depend on this.